# Not sure about the way to approach to the IndexDB API and wrapper libraries?

Tags: html, api, promise

I have started a crash course of IndexDB API. I have heard from the author that the API is a little bit confusing. Primarily, as we have been working with the promise pattern as this API doesn’t use this pattern. Secondary, there are different wrappers, one of them seems is from Github author’s personal library so I suppose he have created it.

However looking for a different flavor, I found this one: http://dexie.org/. Also supports the Promise pattern. See http://dexie.org/docs/Promise/Promise, http://dexie.org/docs/API-Reference#query-items . It seems “promising”.

Also I found that the IndexDB 2.0 API was created post the video time. It is already being supported since beginning of 2017. From a Mozilla developer, I found since Firefox 51 (Jan 2017) it is already there. And he wrote what’s the differences among 1 and 2 versions https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/10/whats-new-in-indexeddb-2-0/

So my question is if at this point is better to use the wrapper libraries or to use the native IndexDB API in terms of cross-browsing and support and better practices?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to do with indexeddb -

1. If you are learning indexeddb for your interest or for knowledge then you should go for plain indexeddb. Learn and research as much you can, because it has too many apis and you will have to write code for every type of situation.
2. You want to use indexeddb in your project and dont have much time to explore indexeddb. You only want to do some database operations and release your project. In this case - you should go for indexedd library. This way you dont need to worry about indexeddb code . You will just write simple code using the library.

For instance : check out this article - https://dzone.com/articles/crud-operation-in-indexeddb-using-jsstore. How a library makes indexeddb so easy.

Hope this will help you.